# Visiting More than one Page in a Describe Block Via Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm writing some super simple integration specs, and while Capybara does simulate the browser/user interaction, I suspect that changing through several pages in one test causes issues. Mainly that the variable `page` doesn't get changed if you visit a few pages in a row. Here's what I mean:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe "The Initial Experience", :type => :feature do
  it "User visits Narrowcontent" do 
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content "Sign In" && "Register"
    click_on "Sign In"
    expect(page).to have_content("Login Access")
    within(".middle-login") do 
      fill_in "user_email", :with => ENV["admin_username"]
      fill_in "user_password", :with => ENV["admin_pw"]
    end
    click_button 'Sign in'
    save_and_open_page
    #expect(page).to have_content("Dashboard")
  end
end
```

I had to comment out the last expectation because it causes the test to fail. The keyword "Dashboard" DOES exist, but the problem is that after running `click_button 'Sign In'`, the variable page still represents the old one, as if `click_button 'Sign In'`has no impact whatsoever.

Any tips?

Comment: For anyone that views this, I figured it out. You can call expect(page.currentpath) to address this issue.